# Is it possible to retrieve the expression provided to a functions parameter as a string?

Tags: php, function, reflection, parameters

I would like to be able to write a function like:

```php
function f($a, $b) {
  $ax = caller_expression($a);
  $bx = caller_expression($b);

  echo "$ax, $bx";
}
```

When I call it like so:

```php
f($object->prop, 2 + 2);
```

I would like the output to be:

```
$object->prop, 2 + 2
```

Can this be done?

Comment: I think that such a thing would break the concept of the function's scope so I don't think such a solution exists. Maybe consider adding the variable name as a string as a third parameter?

Comment: No but you could pass `[$object, 'prop']` and execute that.

Comment: @OfirBaruch that is sort of what I am actually doing in my current implementation but it means a lot of this: `from($something, 'something')` which is tedious and I would like to be able to make that second parameter optional.

Comment: I fail to see a good use case for this though.  Maybe start with the larger problem.